# How to get the list of my Facebook groups in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using **Koala** gem for interaction with Facebook API, I successfully fetched my pages, but I don't know how to obtain the list of groups I am involved in.

How to get this list?

Thanks

Comment: Just do a get request with your access token to the graph api you can explore the graph api and it's objects here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: has my answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You should have `user_groups` when requesting the oauth token from *Facebook*. Then you be able to read groups of a user:

```
@api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth)

groups = @api.get_connections 'me', :groups
puts groups.size
```

And result:

```
134
```